# selenium and javascript, play auto-test with fancybox as a sample

Tags: javascript, selenium, playframework, autotest

As soon as I applied [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) scripts into my playframework application, I can not use **play auto-test** selenium  anymore for test that page where this script is applied. This is because it seems auto-test capabilities can not emulate a real browser's behavior, and as a result I have eternally running test (it's stuck).

So, do you have any suggestion how to act in this situation?

So, I guess that question is what that: **How to use selenium with Javascript libraries (like fancybox) if test is stuck..**

Comment: can you provide the selenium code you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:  http://www.playframework.org/modules/webdrive-0.2/home

Instead of running auto-test use webdrive:test